# Flutter: Home screen will only appear when back button is press after login successfully

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

Provider Code

```
  Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
  }
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode(
          {
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
            'returnSecureToken': true,
          },
        ),
      );
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);

      if (responseData['error'] != null) {
        throw HttpException(responseData['error']['message']);
      }

      _token = responseData['idToken'];
      _userId = responseData['localId'];
      _expiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
        Duration(
          seconds: int.parse(
            responseData['expiresIn'],
          ),
        ),
      );
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
```

Main

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (ctx) => Auth(),
        ),
      ],
      child: Consumer<Auth>(
        builder: (ctx, auth, _) => MaterialApp(
          title: 'Medicare',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
            appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: Colors.white),
          ),
          home: auth.isAuth ? HomeScreen() : WelcomePage(),
          routes: {
            AuthScreen.routeName: (ctx) => AuthScreen(),
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Welcome Screen

[image]

Auth Screen

[image]

Home Screen

[image]

I'm confused about what is missing in my logic when the users log in successfully the main screen wouldn't appear unless I press the back button of my emulator/real device. I'm using a provider for state management and firebase for the back end.

Edit: This is my function for login/sign-up users with errors handler.

```
    try {
      if (_authMode == AuthMode.Login) {
        // Login User
        await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).login(
          _authData['email'],
          _authData['password'],
        );
      } else {
        // Sign Up User
        await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).signup(
          _authData['email'],
          _authData['password'],
        );
      }
    } on HttpException catch (error) {
      var errorMessage = 'Authentication failed';
      if (error.toString().contains('EMAIL_EXISTS')) {
        errorMessage = 'This email address is already in use.';
      } else if (error.toString().contains('INVALID_EMAIL')) {
        errorMessage = 'This is not a valid email address';
      } else if (error.toString().contains('WEAK_PASSWORD')) {
        errorMessage = 'This password is too weak';
      } else if (error.toString().contains('EMAIL_NOT_FOUND')) {
        errorMessage = 'Could not find a user with that email';
      } else if (error.toString().contains('INVALID_PASSWORD')) {
        errorMessage = 'Invalid Password.';
      }
      _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
    } catch (error) {
      const errorMessage =
          'Coult not authenticate you. Please try again later.';
      _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
    }
```

I suspected that there's a context I cannot push because of the httpexception I made.

Comment: Ad good practice, I recommend create individual stateful/stateless widget for login and home, and when the login is success make a push to send to home page

Comment: I'm trying the push/pop navigation but the bug of it is when there is an error during login/signup process, The show dialog widget won't appear.

Comment: Please add some code, i don't see code for dialog

Comment: already added the code which has the dialog and the sign up/login function. Thank you for giving attention on my questions

Answer (score 0):

I did not go in depth but I found an error in the code at the level of braces.

In Provider Code the function Future login, ends up with empty braces!

Check your code

Comment: My bad, I forgot to include it when posting my snippet code. In the original code, the braces are complete

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {

     // empty
     // empty
      // empty
      // empty

  }
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode(
          {
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
            'returnSecureToken': true,
          },
        ),
      );
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);

      if (responseData['error'] != null) {
        throw HttpException(responseData['error']['message']);
      }

      _token = responseData['idToken'];
      _userId = responseData['localId'];
      _expiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
        Duration(
          seconds: int.parse(
            responseData['expiresIn'],
          ),
        ),
      );
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
```